# React Sign Up Form: Issues handling input changes to state

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hooks, user-registration, react-forms

I'm practicing React (with Hooks) where I'm trying to create a simple sign up form (with Hooks) which takes 3 input fields: Name, Email and Password.

For some reason, the controlled component input fields are not updating or allowing the user to enter any values.

**Original Practice Sign-Up Form: (NOT working)**

*Sandbox:*
https://codesandbox.io/s/green-wave-plfszp?file=/src/components/SignUpForm.js

*Code Block:*

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function SignUpForm() {
  const [userState, setUserState] = useState({
    name: "",
    email: "",
    password: ""
  });
  const [submitted, setSubmitted] = useState(false);

  const handleFormSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setSubmitted(true);
  };

  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;

    setUserState((prevProps) => ({
      ...prevProps,
      [name]: value
    }));
  };

  return submitted ? (
    <>
      <p>
        Successfully registered <br />
        Name: {userState.name} <br />
        Email: {userState.email}
      </p>
    </>
  ) : (
    <>
      <h1>Sign-up</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}>
        <label name={userState.name} htmlFor={userState.name}>
          Name:
        </label>
        <br />
        <input
          type="text"
          name={userState.name}
          value={userState.name}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        />
        <br />

        <label name={userState.email} htmlFor={userState.email}>
          Email:
        </label>
        <br />
        <input
          type="text"
          name={userState.email}
          value={userState.email}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        />
        <br />

        <label name={userState.password} htmlFor={userState.password}>
          Password:
        </label>
        <br />
        <input
          type="password"
          name={userState.password}
          value={userState.password}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        />
        <br />

        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
}
```

I tried debugging this in various ways and found another standard login form, which I forked to create a similar version of my original practice sign-up form. This seems to be working perfectly fine.

**Forked Standard Login Form: (working)**

*Sandbox:*
https://codesandbox.io/s/login-form-forked-lj6gmm?file=/src/App.js

*Code Block:*

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    email: "",
    password: ""
  });
  const [submit, setSumbit] = useState(false);

  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setState((prevProps) => ({
      ...prevProps,
      [name]: value
    }));
  };

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setSumbit(true);
    console.log(state);
  };

  return submit ? (
    <div className="App">
      Successfully registered <br />
      Email: {state.email} <br />
      Password: {state.password}
    </div>
  ) : (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div className="form-control">
          <label>Email</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="email"
            value={state.email}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="form-control">
          <label>Password</label>
          <input
            type="password"
            name="password"
            value={state.password}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="form-control">
          <label></label>
          <button type="submit">Login</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

What is the issue in the original practice sign-up form that I created? I'm curious why its working in a certain file only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need change the name of your input from this:

```
  <input
      type="text"
      name={userState.name}
      value={userState.name}
      onChange={handleInputChange}
    />
```

to this:

```
     <input
      type="text"
      name="name"
      value={userState.name}
      onChange={handleInputChange}
    />
```

Note: Just need change the attribute `name` of your input.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I missed out on the fact that I was using the 'value' of the object key instead of the 'key name' itself. 

I used this syntax for maintainability purposes (changing once in the state will reflect changes everywhere, no need to modify it in the form). 

Can only find Object.keys() to do this, but not precisely. Wonder if there is a way to do that; access only a particular key name.

Answer (score 0):

your issue here is that you try to extract the name from event.
if you would try to log the name you extracted it would be empty:

```
 const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    console.log(name)
    setState((prevProps) => ({
      ...prevProps,
      [name]: value
    }));
  };
```

what you can do is pass the prop name on change.

```
      const handleInputChange = (event, propName) => {
    const { value } = event.target;

    setUserState((prevProps) => ({
      ...prevProps,
      [propName]: value
    }));
  };
```

and on your form.

```
<br />
<input
  type="text"
  name={userState.name}
  value={userState.name}
  onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e, "name")}
/>
<br />

<label name={userState.email} htmlFor={userState.email}>
  Email:
</label>
<br />
<input
  type="text"
  name={userState.email}
  value={userState.email}
  onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e, "email")}
/>
<br />

<label name={userState.password} htmlFor={userState.password}>
  Password:
</label>
<br />
<input
  type="password"
  name={userState.password}
  value={userState.password}
  onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e, "password")}
/>
<br />
```